# OpenCV - How to draw a line inside contour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a DIY 3d Scanner project. I'll use a pretty common algorithm for it.
See here: https://lesagegp.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/laser-scanning-explained/
I've totally understood the algorithm and wrote a code for it. All I got to do now is processing the images. I've captured couple images for testing. Here is one of them:[image]

And I've managed to find contours of the laser with a very simple code:

```
image = cv2.imread("frame/1.png")
image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
low_red = np.array([161, 155, 84])
high_red = np.array([179, 255, 255])
red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_red, high_red)
contour = cv2.findContours(red_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
draw_it = cv2.drawContours(image, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("contour",draw_it)
```

Result:[image]

And right now all I want to do is drawing a polyline or something like that inside of contour or inner edge of contour. Like a blue line in this example:[image]

Is there a way to do that and take that line's coordinates? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for the medial axis of the contour?

Comment: @Micka medial or inner axis is fine. I just want to get a single line instead of contour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with a slightly trimmed version of your contour image - which I happen to have generated by other means because your code didn't run on my **OpenCV** version:

[image]

I would then read this as greyscale, and use **skimage** function `medial_axis()` to find the medial axis like this:

```
import cv2
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis

# Load your trimmed image as greyscale
image = cv2.imread("a.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Find medial axis
skeleton = medial_axis(image).astype(np.uint8)

# Save
cv2.imwrite("result.png", skeleton*255)
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, OpenCV, skimage, scikit-image, medial axis, skeleton, skeletonisation.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing. Do you know a way to get a coordinates of white line in result?

Comment: Sure, `X,Y = np.where(skeleton>0)`

Comment: Or, if you want them zipped in pairs `coords = np.column_stack(np.where(skeleton>0))`