# How to get single lines/curves for edges?

Tags: image-processing, scipy, convolution, edge-detection

This is my first experience with image processing. In the jupiter notebook, using scipy , I am trying to convert a gray scale line art image into SVG vector representation. So far I was able to convert the gray scale image to binary (monochrome image) and use sobel filter in x and y axis to get the edges of the drawing. I am getting double lines as edges to account for the both sides of the lines (as shown in below picture and also the code i have used)

I want to replace these double lines with a single one. After that to detect the lines and curves in the drawing and convert them to svg lines and bezier curves. Searching online, i am getting a bit overwhelmed and confused about the proper way forward.  It would be of great help if i can get some pointers about how to proceed from here. If possible i want to do this in scipy only and not with opencv.

Rather than simply using the existing scipy functions and algorithms, I also want to learn about the underlying theory so that i can use them efficiently. So please kindly share any helpful theoretical resources.

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as nd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

def apply_gradient_threshold(d,thres):
    d2 = np.copy(d)
    d2[d2 == -thres] = thres
    d2[d2 != thres] = 0
    return d2


def plot_images(imgs, names):
    fig, axes_list =  plt.subplots(1, len(imgs), figsize=(20, 20))
    for name,axes in zip(names, axes_list):
        axes.set_title(name)

    for img, axes in zip(imgs, axes_list):
        axes.imshow(img, cmap='Greys_r')

    plt.show()  

img_file = <file_url>

img = plt.imread(img_file)
gray_img = io.imread(img_file, as_gray=True) 

if(np.max(gray_img) > 1) :
    gray_img = gray_img/255 #normalize

threshold = 0.2
binary = (gray_img > threshold)*1  # convert the grayscale image to binary (monochrome)

im = binary.astype('int32')
dx = nd.sobel(im,1)
dy = nd.sobel(im,0)
dx = apply_gradient_threshold(dx, 4)
dy = apply_gradient_threshold(dy, 4)
mag = np.hypot(dx,dy) #sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
mag *= 255.0/np.max(mag)

plot_images([binary, mag ], ['Binary - ' + str(threshold), 'Sobel Filter Result'])
```

Comment: This will probably interest you... http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried it and the similar tool autotrace. Potrace also generates doublelines for edges while autotrace does generate centerline but its written in C language.  After playing with them for sometime, I am trying to implement this in python using standard scipy/scikit-image functions. Mainly for learning and also to optimize/customize as per my needs.

Comment: Instead of using Sobel just invert your binary image, it will fix the double lines as edges

Comment: You could look at `medial_axis()` as I used here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913157/2836621

Answer (score 2):

Your image is virtually already made of edges. Use thinning, not an edge filter.