# How to get "1 pixel wide" coordinates from image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, imagemagick, coordinates

I have the following black and white picture of a racetrack:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0HQM.png)

My goal is to convert it into coordinates, similar to this: https://github.com/TUMFTM/racetrack-database/blob/master/racelines/Budapest.csv

What I've tried so far is to use ImageMagick to sort the pixels by color and only keep the black ones, however, this resulted in a large amount of coordinates that were next to each other, while I only intend to have pixels after each other. The plots of my coordinates compared to the ones from the github link:

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQYlx.png)

[Github data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYbJh.png)

I tried to sort out the data, so I'd only include those which have coordinates in a 5 radius circle, but it left out all the data in some sections, while keeping many in others. My question is how such a dataset can be created from an image. As an extra, my next step is to order the coordinates so that they follow the track, I am also looking for ideas there.

Comment: What you want is something that extracts a vector from a bitmap (The "trace bitmap" function in Inkscape can do this), and then use the vector anchors directly (if close enough) or use the Bézier spline math to properly interpolate other points. . There is also a "centerline function somewhere that can help you get the center of the track instead of the sides.

Answer (score 1):

You can thin down to a skeleton like this:

```
magick track.png -alpha extract -morphology Thinning:-1 Skeleton  result.png
```

[image]

---

Note that your image is actually pure black and the information is really in the alpha/transparency channel. You can see that by splitting into the 4 separate RGBA channels and laying them out across the page in a row. R, G and B are black and all the info is in the rightmost A (alpha) channel:

```
magick track.png -separate -background magenta +smush 20 channels.png
```

[image]

---

If you want the x,y coordinates of the white pixels, use:

```
magick track.png -alpha extract -morphology Thinning:-1 Skeleton  txt: | awk -F: '/white/ {print $1}'
101,6
102,6
103,6
104,6
105,6
106,6
107,6
108,6
109,6
118,6
...
...
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `potrace` to generate an SVG of the points:

```
magick track.png -alpha extract pgm: | potrace --svg - > result.svg
```

Gives this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="600.000000pt" height="600.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 600.000000 600.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.16, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2019
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,600.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M0 3000 l0 -3000 1898 2 1897 3 -1730 5 c-1656 5 -1732 6 -1778 24
-191 74 -176 275 36 473 195 182 577 364 857 408 85 14 232 19 785 25 674 9
753 13 802 45 27 18 78 103 95 159 10 34 9 43 -11 81 -44 83 -147 143 -465
269 -103 41 -209 89 -237 106 -134 86 -186 206 -288 662 -98 436 -292 1353
-326 1536 -44 243 -56 371 -53 567 3 141 1 164 -15 188 -10 16 -186 153 -390
306 -205 153 -404 307 -442 343 -79 73 -116 133 -139 224 -74 286 122 517 477
563 38 5 -142 9 -455 10 l-518 1 0 -3000z"/>
<path d="M1310 5993 c201 -15 713 -89 899 -129 134 -29 185 -49 228 -93 37
-37 47 -76 41 -167 l-4 -66 50 -43 c83 -70 549 -417 610 -454 70 -42 137 -51
197 -27 22 9 91 45 153 80 243 138 349 179 461 180 142 2 242 -82 379 -315
284 -483 359 -596 444 -669 71 -60 133 -89 417 -194 277 -103 456 -185 518
-236 48 -40 89 -101 112 -165 30 -87 30 -280 -4 -875 -17 -300 -40 -718 -51
-930 -23 -424 -38 -557 -74 -635 -28 -61 -65 -91 -134 -106 -44 -9 -74 -6
-204 16 -459 80 -637 100 -826 92 -146 -6 -222 -25 -264 -67 -25 -25 -28 -35
-27 -87 1 -77 9 -102 39 -125 43 -31 115 -38 515 -48 425 -11 522 -21 603 -65
68 -37 167 -138 197 -201 79 -166 43 -372 -87 -511 -90 -95 -167 -132 -298
-143 -51 -4 94 -8 358 -9 l442 -1 0 3000 0 3000 -2367 -2 c-1303 -1 -2348 -3
-2323 -5z"/>
<path d="M985 5874 c-11 -2 -51 -12 -90 -20 -128 -30 -225 -96 -273 -188 -21
-41 -26 -64 -25 -116 1 -70 28 -161 63 -210 28 -40 198 -174 540 -427 157
-116 304 -231 327 -255 70 -72 76 -95 74 -313 -2 -231 11 -336 84 -700 87
-438 333 -1554 366 -1665 52 -175 99 -249 191 -296 25 -13 102 -46 170 -73
199 -80 285 -118 357 -160 207 -122 256 -246 167 -426 -50 -101 -96 -146 -172
-169 -52 -16 -122 -19 -629 -26 -905 -13 -945 -16 -1160 -87 -139 -46 -378
-166 -470 -235 -147 -111 -256 -255 -236 -311 12 -33 51 -56 106 -64 28 -5
1132 -8 2455 -8 2300 0 2407 1 2457 18 73 26 145 93 185 174 26 53 32 80 36
149 4 75 2 89 -22 138 -28 57 -119 150 -165 168 -60 24 -125 29 -501 38 -401
9 -523 20 -587 53 -72 38 -123 136 -123 236 0 132 74 214 230 257 52 15 101
18 245 18 200 -1 370 -20 694 -79 107 -19 211 -35 231 -35 87 0 106 81 130
570 6 118 29 540 51 938 32 577 38 738 30 802 -24 189 -82 231 -561 410 -322
120 -392 154 -479 235 -94 88 -146 162 -308 435 -260 438 -274 458 -348 491
-92 42 -184 16 -440 -126 -184 -101 -265 -135 -325 -135 -60 0 -133 27 -215
80 -136 90 -588 436 -639 490 l-49 52 5 82 c6 94 0 112 -46 131 -72 30 -344
79 -729 131 -181 24 -546 41 -602 28z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

---

Another, entirely different option might be to get the medial axis with `scikit-image`, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913157/2836621).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the coordinates of the center of the track with the help of `cv2.ximgproc.thinning` from `opencv-contrib-python`

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('track.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img[img[:, :, 3] == 0] = 255
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
img = ~img
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 100, 100, 100, 100, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

skel = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(img)
skel = skel[100:-100, 100:-100]

coords = np.argwhere(skel == 255)

print(coords)
```

**Result:**

[image: skeleton]